# Tkinter: Error in Terminal, possibly from my key bind?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to SO, and also new to programming. I'm currently experimenting with Tkinter and Python to create a GUI.

My question is related to an error message I am getting in the terminal while my program continues to run un-interrupted.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
class LoginWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.label1 = tk.Label(master, text='User Login')
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(master, text='User Name:')
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.label3 = tk.Label(master, text='Password:')
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.E)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(master)
        self.entry1.focus_set()
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(master)
        self.entry2.config(show='*')
        self.entry2.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(master, text='New User', command=self.new_user_clicked)
        self.button1.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=3, padx=(20,0), pady=5)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(master, text='Login', command=self.login_clicked)
        master.bind('<Return>', self.login_clicked)
        self.button2.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=(0,20), pady=5)
```

This code works just fine, after a successful login I destroy the login window and the main app window opens. However I've noticed that if I press enter (twice for some reason) while the main window is open I get this message in the terminal:

```
2016-12-20 10:43:31.718 Python[1053:71521] IMKInputSession    
presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client    
NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process."    
serInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
```

I've noticed that in other sample GUI's I've built that pressing enter in the same fashion does not give me this error. My suspicion is that I've done something wrong with my key bind. Is this error indicating anything wrong with my code? Or is this just nothing I should worry myself with? My main app is run from a separate class App(tk.Frame) and this login window is a Toplevel() widget.

And I'm not sure this matters or not but I am running this on Mac.

I appreciate the help!
Thanks!

Comment: You've bound `Return` to `login_clicked` so it's probably erroring out when you're already logged in... I'd replace the bind function with another function that checks if the user is logged in before it tries `login_checked`

Comment: I'm not so sure I could get that to work. login_clicked has my code for running the entered credentials against what's in my database. I'm not sure how I could create a function to see if I'm logged in before logging in. I could re-write the way my code runs I suppose. Do you have an example of what you had in mind? The idea behind the bind would be to make it click the login button rather than moving over to click with the mouse.

Comment: I'd think the code for `self.login_clicked` is probably relevant to this question, that certainly doesn't look like a normal python traceback so it is definitely not originating from your tkinter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that the key event is still recorded and tries to run `self.login_clicked` even though you are already logged in.

To fix this, you can create a variable in `__init__` as so:

```
self.is_logged_in = False
```

And in `self.login_clicked` method, you can now detect if the user is already logged in when pressing the button.

```
if self.is_logged_in:
    print("You are already logged in")
else: 
    # code to execute when the user logs in
    self.is_logged_in = True
```